# Automatically submit the same Google Form each 20 min?

Tags: timeout, google-forms

I want to make my google form submit and close automatically within a limited time period.
As an example, I want to close it in 20 min and all answers must be submitted automatically.

Currently the form I made is accessed by multiple users, so to make sure that it is not kept open indefinitely I want it to commit after 20 minutes (at the latest) so that it it freed up again.

I tried this function, but it didn't work out.

```js
var FORM_OPEN_DATE = new Date();
var FORM_CLOSE_DATE = new Date();
FORM_CLOSE_DATE.setMinutes(FORM_CLOSE_DATE.getMinutes()+1);
var sysDate = new Date();
sysDate = sysDate.getMinutes();
function Initialize() {
    deleteTriggers_();
    if (sysDate == FORM_CLOSE_DATE.getMinutes()) {
        closeForm();
        ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm").timeBased().create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more details. What do you have already? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? As it stands the question will most likely be put on hold. As soon as you provide more information it will be reopend and you will receive good answers.

Comment: i have already made a google form,that form is access by concurrent users,but i want google form session close if user open it more than 20 min.

Comment: Ok, what have you already tried? As far as I understand it, google-forms are JavaScripts. Did you search for answers there? Here on SO, we don't like to write your code, but we will be very happy to help you with the next step in your work. So, we need to know where you are standing. What did you already do? Which thought did you already have? - So that we don't suggest solutions to you that won't help you in your situation.

Comment: var FORM_OPEN_DATE= new Date();
   var FORM_CLOSE_DATE= new Date();
FORM_CLOSE_DATE.setMinutes(FORM_CLOSE_DATE.getMinutes()+1);

var sysDate= new Date();
sysDate=sysDate.getMinutes();

function Initialize() {
  
  deleteTriggers_();
  

  if (sysDate ==FORM_CLOSE_DATE.getMinutes()) { 
   closeForm();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm")
    .timeBased()
   
    .create(); 
  }
  

  
}

Comment: I edited the information you gave into your question. Please see if I got it right. If I made a mistake, or you want to add additional information you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42266670/edit) your question at any time. You find that edit link below your question on the left as well.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, why do you want to close the google form or submit it after 20 min. Multiple users can access google form independently and submit their responses at their own pace.